# How to get the namespace-uri of a node in xslt without know element name?

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-business-process

I am using WSO2 BPS 3.2.0 and I want to assign namespace-uri of element to string. Problem is that I don't know element name at design time.

I have XML data

```
<message>
  <Header xmlns="http://schemas.org/Message"/>
  <Body xmlns="http://schemas.org/Message">
    <Container xmlns="http://schemas.org/Container/1.0">
      <Object>
        <document xmlns="http://schemas.org/doc/1.1">dfjgf...ash</document>
      </Object>
      <Object>
        <picture xmlns="http://schemas.org/pic/jpeg/2.0">we54uiytas...h</document >
      </Object>
    </Container>
  </Body>
</message>
```

I try to use XSLT transformation to get **namespace**

```
bpel:doXslTransform("getNamespace.xsl", $Var.message/tns1:Body/tns2:Container/tns2:Object[1])

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <xsl:output method="xml"/>

   <xsl:template match="child::node[position()=1]">
     <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(.)"/>
   </xsl:template>
```

it returns nothing.
If I use output method text it returns all texts contained in xml data.
Where I do mistake?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Which element's namespace do you want to get and - since you won't know it's name - how will you identify it?

Comment: I want to get namespace of child element of Object. Maybe position is not required because there is not other child element in Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:value-of select="namespace-uri(*/*[1])"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will return the namespace of the first child of the root element.

In your example, the root element is `message` and its first child is `Header` - so the result here will be:

```
http://schemas.org/Message
```